# How to make a list of file extensions read only in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a code generation tool (build_runner) that generates source code based on existing source files.

Every generated file is meant to be read-only.

How to tell JetBrains IDE to prevent me (as a developer) to edit those files? (or at least warn me a confirmation dialog before I actually edit the file)

Those files are identified with specific extensions

```
*.generated.dart
*.unwrapped.dart
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your tool set file permissions on the files it generates: `chmod 444`.
2. Make your tool put the files in the `generated` folder like other libraries do.

Sample from Android Studio after setting the file permission on this file and trying to edit it:

[image]